# Recall stored case in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a set of cases that I frequently use to categorize query results and rather than copy/pasting them from a saved file every time I'm hoping I can turn this simplified version of what I use..

```
CASE
WHEN source = 'x' AND othersource  = 'y' THEN 'region'
WHEN subsource = 'm' AND othersubsource = 'n'  THEN 'district'
WHEN littlesource = 'a'  AND otherlittlesource = 'b' THEN 'office'
ELSE 'ERROR - LOOK AT ME'
END AS "Service Channel"
```

Into

```
@RDOCASE
```

Where @RDOCASE is a stored, short-form version of the full case I've listed above. I'm thinking it would be like declaring a variable at the beginning of a query except it's stored somewhere and can be recalled at any time in any query being run on this database.

Answer (score 2):

You should let a computed column do the work for you . . . assuming that the columns all come from the same table:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD ServiceChannel AS (<your case here>)
```

If the values come from multiple tables, then you can use a view for this purpose.  Or perhaps a scalar function, if you want to pass in the relevant variables.

On a side note:  don't use single quotes for column aliases.  This is just confusing.  Single quotes should be used for string and date constants.

Comment: The conditions come from multiple tables. I'm not sure what a scalar function is. What are the relevant variables for a scalar function?

Comment: @bteague . . . A scalar function is a (user-defined) function that returns a single value, as opposed to a function that returns a table.